# Language hint for the code environment

Tags: support, faq, syntax-highlighting

Here on mathematica.stackexchange we will most of the time have to deal with Mathematica code, but it clearly happens too, that someone posts Java-code for JLink or C-code for MathLink, etc. just look at `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Links` to get an idea how many language bindings we have.

[Google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) which is used for highlighting can deal with many languages, but I don't know how good the automatic code recognition works. I checked  [prettify.js](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js) and don't think the automatic detection can handle custom language plugins. Our Mathematica-extension *is* a custom made language-extension to google-prettify, which means we will have to tell at html-basis, that code posted here is `lang-mma`. When the language is fixed, meaning when you make a code-block here it is replace by the editor with something like

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-mma" id="mma">
(* Your code here *)
</pre>
```

every code-block will be highlighted as Mathematica. This seems to be pretty much the same behavior which all SO sites have. You can inspect this by using Chrome and browsing a randomly chosen [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9175543/1078614) or [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9175645/1078614) question, right click on the gray area inside a code block and chose *Inspect Element*. You see that the html-tags are always language specific. If you now draft an answer in the C++ question and post Java-code (use `final` or `instanceOf` to make it crystal clear) and inspect the element in the preview, you see it's still C++. So no language detection.

**Question:** Would it be possible and feasible to highlight code on mathematica.SE always as Mathematica-code, but to have the opportunity to give a hint to the code-environment if the language is something else?

A quick search on meta.SO brought these two related threads to daylight:

- [VB.NET/VBScript syntax highlighting does not properly support comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6812/178346)
- [Improve The Code Tag Highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4813/178346)

There are several more questions about this, but they are tagged `prettify` which suggests, that they talk about the development of prettify and not the inclusion in SO, am I right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81971/164803).

On StackOverflow at least one can specify the language of a code block like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

<!-- language: lang-c -->

    int main() {

        return 0;    
    }
```

This works fine on Mathematica.SE currently:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 Really nice. That was what I hoped for.

Comment: BTW, is there a way to reduce the redundancy here? After "language:" it is clear that there comes a language name, there's absolutely no point in the "lang-" prefix following it.

Comment: @celtschk What comes after *language* is the file-name of the JavaScript which used for highlighting. So it only looks like a redundancy ;-)