# What is your mathematica.stackexchange toolbag?

Tags: discussion

Everyone of us is using this site in a certain way. Beside showing what I use, I really like to see tips, tricks or tools that I'm not aware of.

Therefore, are there certain things in **your** everyday usage of SE that are worth sharing? I'm especially interested (but feel free to post other things too!) in

- What tools, user-scripts, plugins do you use that help you?
- Are you going through new questions in organized way? This is especially important when you weren't on the site for a day and the list of new questions is several pages long?
- How do you use the tag system effectively when looking through questions?
- Is there a better way when searching for a post of a specific user than looking up his ID and using `user:ID` in the search bar?

---

Here are some of my tools:

#### Tools and Scripts:

- I use our [ImageUploader](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/187) most answers I write. Since it is so easy to include images with this, I find myself appending an image of how the result looks for almost all my answers.
- The [additional editor buttons](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/187) are at least as important as the image uploader because you can easily format code and short-keys with it.
- When I try example code that was given by a poster, the [Select Code Block](https://stackapps.com/q/2553) user-script is extremely helpful. When you hover a code-block, then a button appears which let's you select all code instantly. Since the above link doesn't have a downloadable version, you can use the [selectCodeBlock.js](https://gist.github.com/halirutan/2217e4685ae82d754b6c/raw/c439578c08ed464f063f135690edee74e1848f1c/selectCodeBlock.user.js) from my GitHub page.
- For the chat, I learned to love the [SE Chat Modification script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat). This provides simple keyboard short-cuts to reply or quote messages beside another million things it can do. [Read here](http://rchern.github.io/StackExchangeScripts/readme.html) for a complete list of commands

#### Helpful links

- When I need to include code in another language than *Mathematica*, then I want it colorized appropriately. For this you can prepend a [html language hint](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/language-hint-for-the-code-environment/213#213) in front of your code block.
- Very often needed when I want to look up what new users can and cannot do: [The list of priviliges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- When I search the site with the internal search, there is a [good deal of search directives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching) you can use to narrow down the result. Very often, I'm using it search for questions only (`is:Q`). Other times it is helpful to find good questions that need to be answered: `score:3..5 answers:0`
- Since I have enough repuation to help moderate the site, the site with the [moderation tools](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tools) is helpful. You can find it as first tab of the review queue, but I had missed to see this for a long time.
- Remember that in comments you can use quick links like `[chat]` or `[faq]`. For a complete list [see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)
- Although, we have two posts about standardized greeting comments [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138/should-we-have-a-standard-comment-or-practice-for-welcoming-new-users) and [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/standard-greeting-comments), over at TeX.SE they have an extremely [large list of *boilerplate comments*](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) for all kinds of situations. We should probably think about adapting this list for our needs. And while we are at it: The [SE Auto Review Comment script](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc/related) can be used to insert boilerplate comments with one click. I guess adapting this for our site is a matter of some minutes.

Comment: I often find that a google search for Mathematica+terms is useful as well as a search of Stackexchange for terms. It's amazing how often the google answer is here at Mathematica.stackexchange!

Comment: @bills I didn't wanted to add this because I wanted to leave something for others, but are you aware of the `site:mathematica.stackexchange.com` option when using google? This is extremely helpful and brings very often better results that our internal search.

Comment: Perhaps someone can include boilerplate comments here(e.g. the Welcome so M.SE message folks often use for first-time posters)?

Comment: @bobthechemist Right, I forgot about this. I have edited my list of links because at TeX the have a very large list of such comments. One should probably steal it transform it for our site.

Comment: @bobthechemist , halirutan - I thought we already had this: see http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138/8 and the result here http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/597/8

Comment: @Verbeia Yes, I know that we discussed this but plainly forgot to include the links. What I like at the linked page at TeX.SE is that they have a lot of such things for very different situations. Such a list included in the *auto comment* script would be very helpful.

Comment: Would a CW answer to this question containing the [Tex boilerplate comments](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/430) translated for our site be appropriate/beneficial/useful?

Comment: I'm a big fan and frequent user of the additional editor buttons plug-in. I also find it helpful to consult these two sites to resolve some more tricky problems of editing a post: [Markdown Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header) and [TeX Commands available in MathJax](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm)